# Make my app receive a phone call notification

Tags: android, permissions, notifications

My app need to know if the user is current on a phone call or not, then do some response accordingly.

All I need to know if the user is on a phone call or not. I do not need any other rights to deal with anything related to the phone number or any personal information of the user.

What should I do to achieve this? Do I need to get user's permission for it?`enter code here`

Comment: You do need permission [android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes First add these permission to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

You should use Broadcast Receiver with this intent filters.
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL
android.intent.action.NEW_INCOMING_CALL
You can use service for this register. Something like these:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"));
        registerReceiver(receiver2,new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_INCOMING_CALL"));
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

And our Broadcast receiver you can use this:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //
        RequestQueue 
        String savedNumber="";
        String savedNumber2= intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        Log.e("Saved number","Numara: "+savedNumber);
        Log.e("İt is ","İt is it");
        Log.e("Saved number 2 ",savedNumber2);

    }
}
```

And lastly in your manifest file you could use intent filter in your receiver like these:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```